# Card Game Graphics: Updating Vector of Canvas Objects in a Panel

Tags: java, vector, panel

So I am creating the card game Gin Rumy.  I am working on the graphics, specifically, creating a panel that updates so that it always displays the vector of Card objects in the player's hand.  The Cards themselves are a component that extends the canvas class. What I am asking is how to create some function updatePanel() that updates the panel as the player's hand (the vector of Card objects) changes.  All I can think of is to remove the old panel from the GUI frame, create a new panel, fill that new panel with the Cards in the player's hand, and then stick that new panel onto the GUI frame. I haven't even coded this because I worry that taking a component off of the GUI frame and then slapping it back on runs the risk of disrupting the layout, and my gut tells me that creating a new panel every time is just a bad idea. So I'm asking for a better plan.

You'll also notice that the selectButton's actionPerformed() method is incomplete.  What I'm trying to do is remove the cards that have focus.  I understand how focus and action events work, but what I don't understand is how to search through the panel and find the card's that are selected and remove them.

I'd greatly appreciate any help on on either the updatePanel() or selectButton's actionPerformed() method, or any other useful information about adding and removing objects from panels throughout the course of a program.

```
// GraphicGinRumy

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Random;

public class GraphicGinRumy extends GUIFrame {

    protected Card card;
    protected Button selectButton, newGameButton;
    protected Panel controlPanel, playerPanel;
    protected RandomCardDeck deck;
    protected Vector<Card> playerHand;

    //Pardon this weird indentation...the code didn't copy to stack overflow correctly
    public GraphicGinRumy() {
        super("Gin Rumy");
        deck = new RandomCardDeck();
        playerHand = new Vector<Card>();

        MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                Card selectedCard = (Card) e.getSource();
                if (selectedCard.getFocused()) {
                    selectedCard.setFocused(false);
                } else {
                    selectedCard.setFocused(true);
                }
            }
        };

        deck.shuffle();
        rumyDeal();

        //Player Panel
        playerPanel = new Panel();
        for (int c = 0; c < playerHand.size(); c++) {
            playerPanel.add(playerHand.elementAt(c));
        }
        add(playerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Control Panel
        controlPanel = new Panel();
        selectButton = new Button("Select");
        selectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        controlPanel.add(selectButton);
        newGameButton = new Button("New Game");
        newGameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                deck.shuffle();
                deck.deal();
                updatePanel();
            }
        });
        controlPanel.add(newGameButton);
        add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setSize(500, 100);
        setVisible(true);

        //__________________________________________________________________
        //Game Setup
        //__________________________________________________________________

        //Set card values:
        //2 to 9 is worth 5 pts; 10 to K is worth 10 pts; A is worth 15 pts
        for (int c = 0; c < deck.getNumCards(); c++) {
            card = deck.getCard(c);
            if (card.getFaceValue() < 10) {
                card.setValue(5);
            } else if (card.getFaceValue() < Card.ACE) {
                card.setValue(10);
            } else {
                card.setValue(15);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GraphicGinRumy rumy = new GraphicGinRumy();
        //rumy.play();
    }

    protected void rumyDeal() {
        //Give player and CPU 7 cards and add 1 to the discardPile
        Card card;
        int numCards = 7;
        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
            playerHand.add(deck.deal());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
            card = deck.deal();
            card.setVisible(true);
            cpuHand.add(card);
        }
        discardPile.add(deck.deal());
    }

    protected void updatePanel() {
        playerPanel = new Panel();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Card`?  Is it component of some kind??

Comment: Yeah it extends canvas, so you can just treat the card vector like a vector of canvas objects.